# How can I capture the @Html.DropDownListFor selected value?

Tags: c#, razor, enums, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using MVC5, Razor, Entity Framework, C#. I am trying to pass a value of a dorpdown list using a link.

my model is

```
public class TestVM
{
    public string TheID { get; set; }
}
```

I am loading an enum into a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

My enum is

```
public enum  DiscountENUM
{
     SaleCustomer,
     SaleCustomerCategory,
     SaleProduct,
     SaleProductCategory,
     SaleCustomerAndProduct,
     SaleCustomerAndProductCategory,
     SaleCustomerCategoryAndProductCategory,
     PurchaseVendor,
     PurchaseVendorAndProduct,
     PurchaseVendorAndProductCategory,
     PurchaseProduct,
     PurchaseProductCategory,
     Unknown
}
```

I am using the index method of the home controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ListOfDiscounts = SelectListDiscountENUM();
    TestVM d = new TestVM();
    return View(d);
}
```

Where I load the `ListOfDiscounts` using:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListDiscountENUM()
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var listOfEnumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DiscountENUM));

    if (listOfEnumValues != null)
        if (listOfEnumValues.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in listOfEnumValues)
            {
                SelectListItem sVM = new SelectListItem();
                sVM.Value = item.ToString();
                sVM.Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(DiscountENUM), item).ToString();
                selectList.Add(sVM);
            }
        }

     return selectList.OrderBy(x => x.Text).AsEnumerable();
}
```

My create method which is called from the view is

```
public ActionResult Create(TestVM d, string TheID)
{
    return View();
}
```

My `Index` view is

```
@model ModelsClassLibrary.Models.DiscountNS.TestVM

<div>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { TheID = Model.TheID})</div>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TheID, @ViewBag.ListOfDiscounts as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--- Select Discount Type ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

The problem is in the following line in the View

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { TheID = Model.TheID })</div>
```

I have tried adding a model with the name of the field as "TheID"... no luck. Also, added a string field in the parameter, no luck. I looked at the FormControl object, and there was nothing in it either! I suspect something has to be added at the Route level in the helper, but I don't know what.

`Model.TheID` is always null. Even when I select an item in the `DropDownListFor`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can capture the select value of the `DropDownListFor` and send it into the `Html.ActionLink` `TheID`?

Comment: In your controller it looks like you're just creating a default instance of `TestVM` and not setting that property.  So the default value for a `string` property is going to be `null`.  What value do you expect it to have if you never set a value before rendering the page?

Comment: When I render the page, I expect the value to be null. Then I select a value, and I click on the link Create. Now, I expect "TheID" to have the selected value in the DropDownListFor, i.e. when it goes into the controller "Create" - but it doesnt, its still null.

Comment: You're going to need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side code.  Once the page has been sent to the client, the server-side code is no longer executing and can't be re-evaluated.  If you want to modify the link URL client-side then you're going to need to use JavaScript to do that.  Conversely, you can make it a form instead of a link so that the value of the drop down list itself can be used.

Comment: David, You are correct. It works if it is a form and I submit the form. Binding does take place. But I would like it to work with an ActionLink. You say, for me to make it work as an ActionLink, I would need to use Javascript to get the value from the DropDownListFor? Is that correct? Is there no other way for me to pass the value of the DropDownListFor using RouteValues within the ActionLink?

Comment: There is no other way, no.  This would need to happen client-side in the browser, where JavaScript is the language you'd use.  You can't manipulate the page *on the client* with code that runs *on the server*.

Comment: Thank you for your candid answer.

Comment: FWIW, MVC5 has `Html.EnumDropDownListFor`, that's what you should be using with an enum, rather than trying to create your own select list manually.